# Error when setting 2 DataBases without bean annotation using SpringData

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have problem when i try configure 2 dataSources in my xml applicationContext.xml.
The examples i find reffer using bean annotation for configuration. 
i need configuration in xml in my actual architecture.

I saw tutorial:

http://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-multiple-databases

and

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-two-datasources

But i don't solve my problem, the method used in this  Spring page use annotation. I can't use annotation, my configuration is there in xml.
When i try apply seconf datasource has error.

**Before add second datasource, work's fine!
When add second datasource don't work.**

> ***My applicationContext.xml :***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans 
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" 
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" 
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.2.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-4.2.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-4.2.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.2.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-4.2.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd"
    default-autowire="byName" default-lazy-init="true">

    <context:annotation-config />

    <context:component-scan base-package="br.com.myProject" />

    <jpa:repositories base-package="br.com.myProject.ged.repository"/>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean" scope="singleton">
        <property name="jndiName" value="java:jboss/datasources/sgedDS" />
        <property name="resourceRef" value="true" />    
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSourceNurer" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean"  scope="singleton">
        <property name="jndiName" value="java:jboss/datasources/nurerDS" />
        <property name="resourceRef" value="true" />    
    </bean>


    <!--  ************** ENTITY MANAGER SGED ******************** -->

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="br.com.myProject.ged.entity" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />  
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
        </property>

        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">false</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!--  ************** ENTITY NURER NURER ******************** -->    

    <bean id="entityManagerFactoryNurer" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="br.com.myProject.ged.entity" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceNurer" /> 

        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
        </property>

        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">false</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!--  ******** SGED  ******** -->

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <!--  ******** NURER  ******** -->

    <bean id="transactionManagerNurer" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactoryNurer" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" /> <!-- SGED -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManagerNurer" /> <!-- NURER -->


    <bean id="persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" 
          class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.CustomScopeConfigurer">
        <property name="scopes">
            <map>
                <entry key="view">
                    <bean class="br.com.myProject.ged.spring.SpringViewScope" />
                </entry>
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

> **My Bean Service layer:**

```
@Transactional (transactionManager = "transactionManager2")
    public List<DataBase2Entity> getAll(){
        return nurerSituacaoIdrRepository.findAll();
        // return new ArrayList<DataBase2Entity>();
    }


@Transactional (transactionManager = "transactionManager")
    public List<DataBaseEntity> getAll(){
        return nurerSituacaoIdrRepository.findAll();
        // return new ArrayList<DataBaseEntity>();
    }
```

> **My BaseDao.java**

```
public abstract class BaseDao<T>  {

    private Class<T> entityClass;

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "entityManagerFactory")
    private EntityManager em;


    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "entityManagerFactoryNurer")
    private EntityManager emNurer;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public BaseDao() {
        this.entityClass = (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    }

...
```

UPDATE : 02/10/2017
**ERROR execution time:**

```
Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Error setting property values
```

I use same entityManagerFactory or create another entityManagerFactory (see BaseDao.java).

Comment: What exactly is the error and where?

Comment: Hi Arun. I has update. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be an issue with XML.
I see there is a `.` *(dot)* at the end on line no #105

`<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>.`

Remove the dot and try again.

Comment: Thank You. After ajust occur error:     Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Error setting property values

Comment: Whe use same entityManager return error: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]

Comment: cause: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet

Comment: This is because something is not right the the  SQL query. Since you are using HQL (Hibernate) verify that.

Comment: give the HQL query that you use. Mask the confidential data.

Comment: Im use not implementation methods. Im use: ObjectRepository.findAll()

Comment: In that case, the Entity objects are not properly mapped. Make sure the entity classes are matching the Table and entity class's package is specified in the hibernate configuration there by keeping it standard.

Comment: I think it is new EntityManager.          Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerNurer' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Error setting property values

Comment: My configuration many similar this: http://www.codingpedia.org/ama/how-to-setup-multiple-data-sources-with-spring-and-jpa/

Comment: I fix it contect.xml:  Has elements in table, but returned this: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17152190/could-not-extract-resultset

or

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20089031/could-not-extract-resultset-in-hibernate

Comment: i solved my problem. i m using jpql with jpa. i can't use Spring Data, i dont have time now. but i  will searching this solution for future. Your answer helped me. Thank You Arun.